# Android PlayStore warning your app currently targets API level 25

Tags: android, cordova, google-play, app-store

> Warnings Your app currently targets API level 25 and must target at
>   least API level 26 to ensure it is built on the latest APIs optimized
>   for security and performance.
>
> From August 2018, new apps must target at least Android 8.0 (API level
>   26). From November 2018, app updates must target Android 8.0 (API
>   level 26).
>
> Tip: Change your app's target API level. Learn how.

I am using Cordova and Ionic 3.
Just built the app using: `ionic cordova build android --release-prod`

What should I do, ignore this or fix and how?

Thanks.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You can update your cordova-android to 7.0.0 as that's the version that uses SDK 26 as target, or you can update to cordova-android 7.1.4, as it targets SDK 27.

You can do it by removing the platform and adding it again specifying the version to use like this: (if not using ionic, remove the ionic word from both commands)

```
ionic cordova platform rm android
ionic cordova platform add android@7.1.4
```

If you don't want or can't update, you can try to set the target SDK with this preference in the config.xml

```
<preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="26"/>
```

And then run `ionic cordova prepare`

Comment: Superb Man, Adding <preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="28"/> . Worked for me

Answer (score 10):

This is because Google has made it compulsory for apps to target at least 26 API level by August 2018 for new apps and November 2018 for updating apps.

[Docs here.](https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/target-sdk)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by removing the platform and adding it again specifying the version to use like this: (if not using ionic, remove the ionic word from both commands)

ionic cordova platform rm android
ionic cordova platform add android@7.1.4
If you don't want or can't update, you can try to set the target SDK with this preference in the config.xml

And then run ionic cordova prepare

This worked for me!