# Submit app to Google Play results in API level error

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, ionic-framework, google-play-services

Whenever, I submit app I am getting warning about API leve publishing an app on Google Play and I've had a problem with the version of the API, I've already tried to change the API version to the latest version but it does not work . the error message is :

> "Your app currently targets API level 23 and must target at least API level 23 to ensure it is built on the latest APIs optimised for security and performance."

I have used Ionic v1 and already set in config.xml file for level like minSdkVersion, maxSdkVersion, targetSdkVersion

```
  <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="16" />
  <preference name="android-maxSdkVersion" value="26" />
  <preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="26" />

Let me know if any thing need to changes or add.
```

Comment: Error message is Your app currently targets API level 23 and must target at least API level 26 to ensure it is built on the latest APIs optimised for security and performance

Answer (score 1):

Google Play will require that new apps target at least Android 8.0 (API level 26) from August 1, 2018, and that app updates target Android 8.0 from November 1, 2018.

[Meet Google Play's target API level requirement](https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/target-sdk)
and 
[read Another solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51466168/android-playstore-warning-your-app-currently-targets-api-level-25)