# How to resolve the fastlane build error by google api 'your app currently targets API level 28'

Tags: google-play, fastlane

I'm using fastlane to build my android app (written using react native).  I'm fairly new to the app world.  I have a `Fastlane` and a `GoogleService-Info.plist` file if these are relevant.  I've seen some mentioning of this issue online but no actual solution that I could see?!

> Google Api Error: forbidden: Your app currently targets
> API level 28 and must target at least API level 29. - Your app
> currently targets API level 28 and must target at least API level 29.

I have seen this [existing question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51466168/android-playstore-warning-your-app-currently-targets-api-level-25) but as an app newbie I'm not sure how that relates to my world with bitrise/ fastlane.

I've searched my package.json file and there's no reference to google/ google api so rightly (or wrongly) I'm assuming the necessary change is outside the code and hence maybe something in the fastlane/ google files I mention above.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I have the answer! hurrah

I also have a `build.gradle` file that has a reference to the target sdk version which is currently set to 28, change it to 29, shown below -

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "28.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 16
        compileSdkVersion = 28
        targetSdkVersion = 29
        supportLibVersion = "28.0.0"
    }
```

This should fix the problem